# How to filter the physical port of the switch through snmp?

Tags: switch, network, snmp

I tried using snmp to get **ifdescr**, I think the interface name containing **Ethernet** might be a physical port, but I am not sure.

In addition, the interface in **dot3StatsIndex** is also like a physical port, which is also not sure.

Is there any other idea or a solution to the problem?

Comment: Port naming conventions are vendor specific. You should specify which brand and model of switch you're trying to check.

Comment: Is there a uniform standard that can be used? Are there any consistent standards for all of different brands?

Comment: No, hence 'vendor specific'. Vendors are free to chose their own naming scheme, there's not one standard for all brands.

Comment: This is not good news for me. I will contact the brand to ask tomorrow.

Comment: If you tell us which brand you're looking at, we may be able to tell you what their naming scheme is.

Comment: If you have this information, the more the better. I am mainly looking for Cisco, Huawei, H3C.

Comment: I need you help,sir.

Comment: There is no 'easy' way, afaik. Comparison of `ifDescr` or `ifName` from IF-MIB with information returned for `entPhysicalName`, `entPhysicalClass` (=port or container), `entPhysicalDescr` in ENTITY-MIB, can be useful. Also, simple check  `IF-MIB::ifConnectorPresent`=`true` might be enough to find connected physical interfaces.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use ifType from the interfaces MIB ([IF-MIB](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/interfaces.html)). However, there's a *lot* of different interface types [as you can see](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/interfaces.html#IANAifType), and it's up to the individual vendor to correctly populate this table. In any case, there's most likely not one single value you can match on, a number of types can be used for physical interfaces, *especially* if you're also dealing with protocols other than ethernet (ATM for example).